# haproxy : http frontend to https backend

Tags: haproxy

This is the exact same question as [http request to https request using haproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094066/http-request-to-https-request-using-haproxy)

However, the accepted answer does not work for me and I dont understand why

haproxy.cfg:

```
global
  daemon
  maxconn 15
  defaults
  mode tcp
  balance first

frontend google
  bind *:10005
  default_backend google-url

backend google-url
  server xxx google.com:443 ssl verify none
```

when I call `curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:10005'`, I receive a response that comes from google but with a 404 status

> The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

I tried both mode tcp and mode http, same result

If I activate the logs with

```
  mode http
  bind *:10005
  default_backend google-url  
  option httplog
  log stdout format raw local0
```

I have this

```
  127.0.0.1:52588 [16/Jun/2022:08:24:49.976] google google-url/xxx 0/0/49/20/69 404 1884 - - ---- 2/2/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
  127.0.0.1:52588 [16/Jun/2022:08:24:49.938] google google/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/1038 400 0 - - CR-- 2/2/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
```

In case this has some impact, I'm running haproxy in kubernetes and then I "port-forward" 10005 (but this does not seem to be the issue because the logs demonstrate that haproxy is correctly receiving the request and using the correct backend...)

Answer (score 2):

Your curent HAProxy configuration will accept your request:

`curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:10005'`
(corresponds to the first log entry)

and proxy it to Google as:

`curl  --location -H 'Host: localhost' --request GET 'https://www.google.com/'`
(note the `Host` header implied; I bet this is not what you'd expect).

Google will respond with 404 and HAProxy will log the `BADREQ`.

This happens because HAProxy can't infer that when client request's `Host` header is `localhost` it should re-write it to `google.com` (or better: `www.google.com`) simply because it proxies to a host with that name.

You need to configure:

```
backend google-url
  server xxx google.com:443 ssl verify none
  http-request set-header host www.google.com
```